# Which resolution i will use for retina display iphones - media query

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I am using iPhone4 to test my responsive website

I had read that retina display will show 1px as 2px...

so my doubt is in landscape the device width 480px, screen resolution 640px..

but which one i want to use

```
@media only screen (max-device-width : 480px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
```

or

```
@media only screen (max-device-width : 640px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No matter what their resolution, you target all iPhones at 320px in portrait mode, and iPhone4S and under stick with 480px in landscape mode. (5 is a little wider in landscape.)

Comment: then what is the purpose of max-device-width : 480px instand of this can we use @media only screen and (max-width: 480px)

Comment: Yes, that's still all needed, and I recommend using `max-width` rather than `max-device-width`. So, `@media only screen (max-width: 480px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {}` If you don't use `and (orientation: landscape)`, the styles will apply in portrait view as well.

Comment: so the @media only screen (max-device-width : 640px) and (orientation : landscape) only use to over write the css?

Comment: Is i need to change and zoom level or scale level for retina display?